# How do you use Clang-format on Emacs, Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, emacs, clang, clang-format

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux, so I'm sorry if this question seems to be too stupid. I hoped to have a function that can automatically format my C++ codes, so I installed `clang-format` by the following terminal command:

```
sudo aptitude install clang-format
```

To make it work with Emacs, I searched on the Internet for a solution and modified my "~/.emacs" file, adding the following line:

```
(setq clang-format-executable "/usr/bin/clang-format-6.0")
```

Now in Emacs, when I used the command `M-x clang-format-buffer` or similar commands on a C++ file, it succeeded, but the source code didn't seem to be formatted at all (sorry that I can't directly post images for some reason):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNIvn.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKLXl.png

Is there anything else I'm missing in setting up clang-format, or what's the proper way to set it up?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

First, installing Clang-format this way was unnecessary. The proper way to do it was by using Emacs' package-install command.

```
package-install clang-format
```

Then I did this in the .emacs file:

```
(load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/clang-format-6.0/clang-format.el")
```

Hope this helps anyone facing the same problem.